# Open byte[] type image in a browser by using <a href="..">

Tags: html, blob

Are there any ways to open byte[] type image in browser by only using

```
<a href ="..">Image To Open</a>
```

For example I can open Image in browse if I know a path in a file system:

```
<a href ="/Images/image.jpg">Image To Open</a>
```

But what if I only have byte[] array and content type of image (retrieved from db). Are there any ways to fill *href* attribute with a data I have to fulfill my needs ?

Comment: You're looking for `data:` URIs.

Comment: @SLaks thanks, It works on testing page and now I know that I have more problems :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yea u gotta base64 encrypt your bytearray

and then set the href like so:

```
data:image/jpg;base64,yourbase64encryptedstring
```